# Как найти элемент и его свойства в xsd схеме

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server, xsd

Мне нужно создать БД в ms sql на основе xsd схемы, для этого я использую `DataSet`

```
DataSet temp = new DataSet();
temp.ReadXmlSchema("schema.xsd");            
temp.ReadXml("xml_file.xml");
```

Затем для каждого столбца в `DataTable` я создаю команды:

```
SqlCommand createtable = new SqlCommand("create table " + dt.TableName + " (" + 
dc.ColumnName + "  varchar(max))", conn);
createtable.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

или так:

```
SqlCommand addcol = new SqlCommand("alter table "+ dt.TableName+" 
add "+dc.ColumnName+" varchar(max)", conn);
addcol.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Но проблема состоит в том что мне необходимо брать типы колонок и прочего из xsd схемы, а не использовать `varchar(max)`:

```
<xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:Length value="20"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Другими словами мне нужно получить `restriction` для элемента, имя которого - имя колонки из `DataTable` и родитель у которого - элемент с именем как у соответствующей таблицы `DataTable`, т.к. есть элементы в схеме с одинаковыми именами.
Я знаю что у `DataColumn` есть свойства, но только `MaxSize`. Про Altova я тоже знаю, но мне необходима именно реализация в "коде".

Comment: а почему не использовать ORM?

Comment: @Bald56rus я, к сожалению не знаю что это такое, если вы покажете на примере что вы имеете ввиду буду вам безмерно благодарен

Comment: [Руководство по Entity Framework](http://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/index.php) это вариант не единственный есть другие. просто я его использую.

Comment: Я могу на основе xsd создать эту модель автоматом и отобразить ее потом в бд?

Comment: ниже в ответе Вам уже ответили на данный вопрос:) </br> >Кстати, интересный вопрос - а используемая схема известна на этапе компиляции или нет? Если известна, то можно сгенерировать по ней класс для десериализации, после чего этот класс отобразить в базу средствами EF.

Comment: На словах я не очень понятно если честно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Технически, все простые типы данных в XSD - это наследники `xs:string`, так что вы не столь и неправы, отображая их все на `varchar(max)` (хотя я бы рекомендовал всегда использовать `nvarchar`).

Но, конечно же, есть некоторые частные случаи, которые можно выразить типами данных, отличными от строкового. Попробуйте проверять `dc.DataType` и уже на его основе выбирать тип данных SQL.

Кстати, интересный вопрос - а используемая схема известна на этапе компиляции или нет? Если известна, то можно сгенерировать по ней класс для десериализации, после чего этот класс отобразить в базу средствами EF.

Если же схема заранее не известна, а требуется выполнять более тонкое отображение, чем возможно средствами DataSet - всегда можно прочитать схему в объект XmlSchema и разобрать ее самостоятельно.

Comment: Можно подробнее про то как из схемы сделать модель и отобразить ее в бд? В `XmlSchema` пробовал, проблема в том что не могу понять как в рекурсии создавать таблицы и на каком основании?

Comment: К примеру, можно сгенерировать классы программой xsd.exe

Comment: схема БД известна? откуда берется файл "schema.xsd" - описывающий бд?

Comment: @Bald56rus входящий файл - схема, пока задача в том чтобы создать бд на его основе и записать туда данные из xml

Comment: @e1s мне не совсем понятно что Вы хотите получить в итоге: инструмент для динамического создания БД на основании схемы(*.xsd файл) либо же у Вас стоит задача создать конкретную БД разово, и наполнить её данными из xml. почему БД должна создаваться именно так а не например средствами Entity Framework(любой другой) или в дизайнере(в том каком удобно)

Comment: @Bald56rus Инструмент для динамического создания БД, просто я не знаком с EF и отсюда неоднозначности. Сейчас пролистал и понял что с ним маловероятно получится динамически создавать.

Comment: @e1s тогда как писали Выше ручной разбор схемы